# Unable to fetch a value from JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to get a value from the JSON which I am getting through Ajax.

Here is the example of what I am working on
http://jsfiddle.net/NNrcp/6/.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22sta%20India%22&format=json",
    success:function(result){

        jQuery("#div1").html("<pre>"+result+"</pre>");

        console.log(test.query.results.place[0].woeid);
        document.getElementById("jname").innerHTML=test.query.results.place[0].woeid;

    }
});
```

If I remove the Ajax part and hardcode the JSON, then it works properly but I am unable to make it work using Ajax.

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The fiddle seems to work fine for me. It shows `Name: 2282863`.

Comment: it didnt work for me.. after adding the dataType, it worked 
http://jsfiddle.net/NNrcp/7/

Comment: @FelixKling he could be using an old jQuery version (where mime-type detection was not yet implemented) ?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.9.1 . It there in the fiddle..

Comment: @lostsource: Yeah, I was thinking about that as well, but apparently they are not... I don't know, it's a mystery ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `dataType` property to your request

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:"..",
    success:function(result){
      ..
    },
    dataType: "json"  // <---
});
```

Comment: The response is sent with the right content type (`application/json`), so jQuery is able to figure this out by itself.